# How can one change the location of the "webapp" directory for a Scalatra application?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

By default, Scalatra expects the "webapp" directory to be at `src/main/webapp`. How could that be changed to, e.g., `content/doc-root`?

sbt allows for customizing its default directories using something like the following:

```
scalaSource <<= (baseDirectory)(_ / "src")
```

So I assume it's just a matter of knowing the right "configuration key" to use...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Kelsey Gilmore-Innis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884064/3827) has the right answer, but since it's not accepted let's break it, break it, break it down.

First, I'm assuming you're following [Getting started guide](http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html) to install Scalatra using `g8`. Hopefully the same version I just got.

### g8 scalatra/scalatra-sbt

What that g8 template did was to set up an sbt 0.13 build which uses [scalatra-sbt](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt) 0.3.2 plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalatra.sbt" % "scalatra-sbt" % "0.3.2")
```

This plugin internally uses [JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) 0.4.0 to do the webapp-related settings.

### xsbt-web-plugin 0.4.0

This is why xsbt-web-plugin becomes relevant even though you just want to change Scalatra's setting. The setting you need to rewire is called `webappResources in Compile`. How does that work?

### rewiring webappResources

To rewire the setting, open `project/build.scala`. Add

```
import com.earldouglas.xsbtwebplugin.PluginKeys.webappResources
```

to the import clauses. Then change settings as follows:

```
  lazy val project = Project (
    "foo",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ ScalatraPlugin.scalatraWithJRebel ++ scalateSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
      webappResources in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "content" / "doc-root"),
      ...
    )
  )
```

Now move `src/main/webapp` to `content/doc-root`, reload sbt, and that should be it.

Answer (score 4):

The resource folder is a Jetty property. If you're running embedded Jetty, it's specified [here](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-embedded-jetty.g8/blob/master/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package%24/JettyMain.scala#L24). You can edit it manually or override by setting the PUBLIC environment variable.

You also can override it in your SBT build file. It uses the xsbt-web-plugin to run, and you [can override that plugin's settings](https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/wiki/Settings).

Answer (score 1):

For newer version of xsbt-web-plugin (1.0.0 as of writing) the way of changing source path is different.

First of all corresponding settings were moved to `XwpPlugin.webappSettings`. And you needs these two

```
webappSrc in webapp <<= (baseDirectory in Compile) map { _ / "content" / "doc-root" },
webappDest in webapp <<= (baseDirectory in Compile) map { _ / "content" / "doc-root" },
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you dont want to change the sbt settings**, you can also do it programmatically by overriding serveStaticResource and using forward

```
override protected def serveStaticResource(): Option[Any] = {
  // check to see if we need to alter the path to find the TRUE disk url
  val incUrl = request.getRequestURI

  if(incUrl.startsWith("/otherDir")) {
    servletContext.resource(request) map { _ =>
      servletContext.getNamedDispatcher("default").forward(request, response)
    }
  } else {
     val trueUrl = "/otherdir" + incUrl
     Option(servletContext.getRequestDispatcher(trueUrl).forward(request, response))
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: You should also check that it doesn't go into an infinite loop.